# Can not remove sql server 2008 and sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, hosting

I have installed sql server 2008 and sql server 2012 in plesk but the problem I am facing is I have database in 2014 and I want to import that database to plesk but I am not able to install sql server 2014 because of previous versions installed and I can't remove that version please check this image

[please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTuRD.png)

how to remove sql server 2008 and sql server 2012 from plesk and install sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove MSSQL server from Plesk by design, so you should do it manually using OS native tools. Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features
Check Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup) for details.
Anyway you should be able to install SQL Server 2014 without removing other instances using Plesk.